# Error when getting groups for a particular email ID with Java google apps directory API

Tags: java, google-apps

I want to get groups for a particular email ID in Google Apps with the help of the Java Google Apps Directory API but I am getting an error.

Can someone help explain what the error is and what in my code might be causing it? The error and related code follows.

**Error:**

```
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory;
import com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Group;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;

public class Test {
    private static Bigquery bigquery;  
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
        SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group");
        SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");


        GoogleCredential credential =  new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("244204474315-l08ah6g350oofeosi7p8pqmotlrmgion.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setServiceAccountUser("244204474315-l08ah6g350oofeosi7p8pqmotlrmgion@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                    new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\nbaser\\Desktop\\76ba0ac39b06e8419bbb670734f3b2affeec43b2-privatekey.p12"))
            .build();


        Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

//      Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list();
//      list.setDomain("yourDomain.com");
//      Users users = list.execute();


        //Directory.Users.Get user = directory.users().get("nishant.baser@ahold.com");
        //user.get

        Directory.Groups.Get group = directory.groups().get("ausa.googleams.group@ahold.com");
        Group groups = group.execute();

//      Directory.Members.List list = directory.members().list("ausa.googleams.group@ahold.com");

//      Members members = list.execute();

//      System.out.println(members);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `Builder#setApplicationName` in your `new GoogleCredential.Builder()`.